# R: Convert contingency table to long data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe

Consider you are given a summarized crosstable like this:

```
kdat <- data.frame(positive = c(8, 4), negative = c(3, 6),
                   row.names = c("positive", "negative"))
kdat
#>          positive negative
#> positive        8        3
#> negative        4        6
```

Now you want to compute Cohen's Kappa, a statistic to determine the agreement between two raters. Given data in this format, you can use `psych::cohen.kappa`:

```
psych::cohen.kappa(kdat)$kappa
#> Warning in any(abs(bounds)): coercing argument of type 'double' to logical
#> [1] 0.3287671
```

Which irks me, because I prefer my data to be long and thin, which would let me use `irr::kappa2`. A similar function that I prefer for arbitrary reasons. So I assembled this function to reformat my data:

```
longify_xtab <- function(x) {
  nm <- names(x)
  # Convert to table
  x_tab <- as.table(as.matrix(x))
  # Just in case there are now rownames, required for conversion
  rownames(x_tab) <- nm
  # Use appropriate method to get a df
  x_df <- as.data.frame(x_tab)

  # Restructure df in a painful and unsightly way
  data.frame(lapply(x_df[seq_len(ncol(x_df) - 1)], function(col) {
    rep(col, x_df$Freq)
  }))
}
```

The function returns this format:

```
longify_xtab(kdat)
#>        Var1     Var2
#> 1  positive positive
#> 2  positive positive
#> 3  positive positive
#> 4  positive positive
#> 5  positive positive
#> 6  positive positive
#> 7  positive positive
#> 8  positive positive
#> 9  negative positive
#> 10 negative positive
#> 11 negative positive
#> 12 negative positive
#> 13 positive negative
#> 14 positive negative
#> 15 positive negative
#> 16 negative negative
#> 17 negative negative
#> 18 negative negative
#> 19 negative negative
#> 20 negative negative
#> 21 negative negative
```

...which let's you compute Kappa via `irr::kappa2`:

```
irr::kappa2(longify_xtab(kdat))$value
#> [1] 0.3287671
```

My question is:
Is there a *better* way to do this (in base R or with a package)? It strikes me as a relatively simple issue, but by trying to solve it I realized that it's oddly tricky, at least in my head.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is some public domain code from: http://www.cookbook-r.com/Manipulating_data/Converting_between_data_frames_and_contingency_tables/ which I have used to do exactly what you have asked.

```r
# Convert from data frame of counts to data frame of cases.
# `countcol` is the name of the column containing the counts
countsToCases <- function(x, countcol = "Freq") {
    # Get the row indices to pull from x
    idx <- rep.int(seq_len(nrow(x)), x[[countcol]])

    # Drop count column
    x[[countcol]] <- NULL

    # Get the rows from x
    x[idx, ]
}
```

Comment: so for op example: `d = as.data.frame(as.table(as.matrix(kdat))) ; 
countsToCases(d)`

Comment: Now I feel silly because at one point when I started with R I read through the entire Cookbook and I _know_ I once scrolled past this function. Thanks for the answer, I'll accept this one as a solution because it uses base R and is already published public domain code.

Answer (score 6):

```
kdat <- data.frame(positive = c(8, 4), 
                   negative = c(3, 6),
                   row.names = c("positive", "negative"))

library(tidyverse)

kdat %>%
  rownames_to_column() %>%            # set row names as a variable
  gather(rowname2,value,-rowname) %>% # reshape
  rowwise() %>%                       # for every row
  mutate(value = list(1:value)) %>%   # create a series of numbers based on the value
  unnest(value) %>%                   # unnest the counter
  select(-value)                      # remove the counts

# # A tibble: 21 x 2
#    rowname  rowname2
#      <chr>    <chr>   
# 1 positive positive
# 2 positive positive
# 3 positive positive
# 4 positive positive
# 5 positive positive
# 6 positive positive
# 7 positive positive
# 8 positive positive
# 9 negative positive
# 10 negative positive
# # ... with 11 more rows
```

Comment: Thanks, it's a good tidyverse alternative but I think due to the general nature of the question I'll accept the base R answer. Nice piping though!