# How to convert a multidimensional contingency table to tidy data?

Tags: r, tidyr

I have a raw multidimensional contingency table that I want to convert to tidy data or other long form so that I can fit a logistic regression on it. I have found great [methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48331207/5947569) for portions of it. But I'd like a strategy for dealing with whole thing iteratively.

Here's a half of it formatted:

```
                           White           
                   <35     35-44     >44   

Region           M    F    M   F    M    F 

Northeast
 Satisfied      288   60  224  35  337   70
 Not satisfied  177   57  166  19  172   30

Mid-Atlantic
 Satisfied       90   19   96  12  124   17
 Not satisfied   45   12   42   5   39    2

Southern
 Satisfied      226   88  189  44  156   70
 Not satisfied  128   57  117  34   73   25
```

Here's the full raw data, stripped of its headers:

```
> dput(df_raw)
structure(list(V1 = c(288L, 177L, 90L, 45L, 226L, 128L), V2 = c(60L, 
57L, 19L, 12L, 88L, 57L), V3 = c(224L, 166L, 96L, 42L, 189L, 
117L), V4 = c(35L, 19L, 12L, 5L, 44L, 34L), V5 = c(337L, 172L, 
124L, 39L, 156L, 73L), V6 = c(70L, 30L, 17L, 2L, 70L, 25L), V7 = c(38L, 
33L, 18L, 6L, 45L, 31L), V8 = c(19L, 35L, 13L, 7L, 47L, 35L), 
    V9 = c(32L, 11L, 7L, 2L, 18L, 3L), V10 = c(22L, 20L, 0L, 
    3L, 13L, 7L), V11 = c(21L, 8L, 9L, 2L, 11L, 2L), V12 = c(15L, 
    10L, 1L, 1L, 9L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Here's how I can take care of one section:

```
ne35 <- data.frame(c(288, 177), c(60, 57))
colnames(ne35) <- c("Male", "Female")
rownames(ne35) <- c("Sat", "Unsat")

ne35 %>%
  rownames_to_column() %>%            # set row names as a variable
  gather(rowname2,value,-rowname) %>% # reshape
  rowwise() %>%                       # for every row
  mutate(value = list(1:value)) %>%   # numbers based on the value
  unnest(value) %>%                   # unnest the counter
  select(-value)                      # remove the counts

# A tibble: 582 x 2
rowname rowname2
<chr>   <chr>   
  1 Sat     Male    
2 Sat     Male    
3 Sat     Male    
4 Sat     Male    
5 Sat     Male    
6 Sat     Male    
7 Sat     Male    
8 Sat     Male    
9 Sat     Male    
10 Sat     Male    
# … with 572 more rows
```

I am stumped, however, on how to apply this to a few tiers of categorical variables.

Comment: Hi, could you paste the output of `dput(<yourData>)` into your question or  `dput(head(<yourData>))` if it's too large?

Comment: Done! Is that output generally helpful to include?

Comment: It's always wise to include code and data to provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). However, because your new data seems to be slightly different from the ones you entered above as "halfway formatted", it's not entirely clear what you want.